# Conformal harmonic maps in high dimensions are scaled isometries

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, isometry

It is well-known that conformal maps between $2$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds are harmonic.

I discovered lately that in dimension $d>2$, conformal harmonic maps must be scaled isometries (The conformal factor is constant).

This is a "rigidity phenomena"- in stark contrast to the $2$D case, in higher dimensions the set of conformal and harmonic maps is very "small".

I am quite sure this should be already known, but couldn't find a reference.
Any help?

Comment: I saw it stated in the literature (but without a reference).

Comment: Thanks, do you remember where did you see it? (although as you said, it probably won't be of much help, since there is no reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting [in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267864/conformal-harmonic-maps-in-high-dimensions-are-scaled-isometries/267886#267886), it turns out that:

Indeed, the result can be found in the book Harmonic morphisms between Riemannian manifolds, by Paul Baird, John C. Wood.

The relevant statement is Corollary 3.5.2.